# Bash Script Case statement (if-not logic)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting

I wrote a small bash script. It will try to find the word **ERROR**. If found the resulting value will be non-zero numeric (for example 25. I mentioned in the script but it is variable numeric value), and if not found, it will be 0.

My problem is: I want to use `case` statement, such that if output is not zero, then execute the following command

```
truncate -s 0 /root/test/wayfile.log && screen -X -S wowow quit &
```

Script here:

```
#! /bin/bash

case "$(grep ERROR /root/test/wayfile.log | wc -w)" in

25)  echo "empty log file and kill screen: $(date)" >> /var/log/finderror.txt
    truncate -s 0 /root/test/wayfile.log && screen -X -S wowow quit &
;;
0)  # all ok
;;
esac
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option: tell `case` to look for a `0`, in which case: do nothing; *otherwise*, execute your command:

```
case X in
  (0) : ## do nothing
      ;;
  (*) truncate ...
      ;;
esac
```

Another option: tell `case` to look for any non-zero digit:

```
case X in 
  ([123456789]) truncate ...
esac
```

... but instead of trying to match numbers with `case`, I would use `test`:

```
if [ "$(grep -c ERROR /root/test/wayfile.log)" -gt 0 ]
then
  truncate ...
fi
```

I've simplified `grep ... | wc -w` to just `grep -c`, which asks `grep` to do the counting instead of involving `wc`.

Further, since you're *really* just interested in whether the word `ERROR` exists at all in the file, you can just ask `grep` if it's there:

```
if grep -F -q ERROR /root/test/wayfile.log
then
   truncate ...
fi
```

The `-F` flag tells grep that our search text is plain ("Fixed") text -- no regular expressions; the `-q` flag tells grep to be "quiet" -- don't count or output matching lines, just set its exit status based on whether it found the search text at all (or not). A successful exit code (of 0) indicates that the search text was found at least once in the file; failure indicates that the search text was not found at all in the file.

Comment: very cool (+1). Or even  `grep -q ERROR ex1 &&   truncate ....`